# Relative speed with bike on train

Tags: kinematics, inertial-frames, relative-motion

If I am riding a bike on top of a train will the speed of the bike relative to the train and the speed of the train relative to the ground be added?

For example: bike going 5mph train going 50mph. If I used a speedometer would I be going 55mph or 5mph?

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Surely if you used a speedometer on your bike it would indicate 5mph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your speedometer would read 5 mph as it measures your speed as apposed to the surface of the train. A traffic cop with a radar gun would measure the train at 50 mph and you at 55 mph relative to his stationary position. If the traffic cop was driving at 55 mph in the same direction as you he would measure your speed as zero.

Answer (score 0):

The speedometer would read 5mph because it measures speed according to the ground it's on. If you were to lift your bike up off the ground and you rid it, the speedometer wouldn't say 0mph even though you aren't really moving.